# Usage of DependencyProperty and ObservableCollection on class models

Tags: list, mvvm, xml-serialization, dependency-properties, observablecollection

I just starting on WPF with MVVM, so forgive any misconceptions. I have a model (not a view model but the actual model) that has many List inside classes that are in other List making trees of data.

Important, the data should be XML Serializabled, currently there is no problem doing that with regular properties and List.

The View Model of this class is taking a lot more work than I expected and I'm thinking on converting some or maybe all of the List to ObservableCollections, what are the pros and cons of that?

Also, what would be best in a "bindable model", NotifyPropertyChange or DependencyProperties? I think there would be some memory gains with DependencyProperty since many objects will use default values on most of the properties, what about performance in general, and has it any problems with serialization?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The View Model of this class is taking a lot more work than I expected and I'm thinking on converting some or maybe all of the List to ObservableCollections, what are the pros and cons of that?

There is a bit more overhead in `ObservableCollection<T>` when compared to `List<T>`, but it does make it easier as data binding directly to your model collections will work.

> Also, what would be best in a "bindable model", NotifyPropertyChange or DependencyProperties?

I would not use DependencyProperties within your model.  This is taking a dependency on the WPF libraries, and very platform specific.  If you want to be able to data bind directly to your model, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a reasonable approach.

However, you really should stop and take a minute before making any of these changes.  If you're changing your model classes primarily to use them in your View, you're violating the basic principles of MVVM (and most other architectural patterns).  One of the main goals here is that your Model is unaware of the presentation layer being used - this makes it more flexible in the future, as you can change presentation layers without changing your model at all.

Comment: Reed, right now, I'm two levels deep in my structure, and my ViewModel has already 4 properties being created just to "mirror" data. I have to mirror a List in a BindingList and bind a SelectedItem to a CurrentItem property and use this property to bind another List to a second BindingList (second level). This is getting confuse as my model goes up to 6 levels deep. I guess MVVM is not the solution in this case.

Comment: @Luiz: No - you're trying to model everything up front, from the sounds of it.  The trick is to break it up - a ViewModel only needs to re-wrap the objects its view is presenting, not your entire model.  As you go "down" in your hierarchy, you can construct other VM's from that specific portion of the model, and wrap them as needed.  (BTW - I'd use an ObservableCollection instead of BindingList in your VMs)

Comment: BTW, I still want to make the Model unware of the View, I just want to make it more "bindable" to make my work on the view easier. The ViewModel as it is now is adding a layer of deep complexity that seems like is too much.

Comment: @Luiz: Using DP would create a dependency in your Model on WPF.  That's making it aware of the fact that WPF is what's using it.  You can use ObCol<T>, etc - but I wouldn't use DP...

Comment: @Reed, my presentation will have most of the time at least 4 levels show on screen. Something like Category -> Subcategory -> Item -> Properties. Those properties go even deeper but I will probably bring it on another window.

Comment: @Reed, I don't think I will need dependecyproperties or maybe even the notify interface, my biggest concern is the observable collection. Also about the collection, how to add a new item using MVVM pattern, since you should avoid naming components and only bind items?

Comment: @Luiz: You typically handle this in the ViewModel - adding to an ObservableCollection works fine here.  As for your "levels" - this is normal Master-Detail work, and typically handled via ViewModels/DataTemplates (quite easily, too )

Comment: @Reed, the question about adding was how for example I would add a new property on the current item of the current subcategory of the current category without using names or some binding to SelectedItem? The only exposed public property would be Categories, all the rest will be deep down.

Comment: You'd typically do it in the ViewModel "deep down" - you're trying to put too much into "one level" instead of letting the system handle this via DataTemplates, etc...